# How to getting current Email that be used for login in Myth/Auth library Code Igniter 4

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-4

I wanted to make a program that able to store a data and every the data that i send to the Database must contain the Email from user used to login to my Web. In here i'm using [Myth Auth](https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth) library as authenticator and login security. But i can't find the method to call the current Email so i can fetch it and push to my Database. i'm using MySql as my DB.

[image: The sample Database table]

Comment: From the "Myth Auth" github doc, I noticed that there's a [helper function](https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth#helper-functions) `user()`. Did it not return user related data along with user's email?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an Entity extending Mith's one.
So create app/Entities/User.php

Then... to use:

echo user()->getEmail();

See Documentation:
https://github.com/lonnieezell/myth-auth/blob/develop/docs/extending.md

```
<?php namespace App\Entities;

use Myth\Auth\Entities\User as MythUser;

class User extends MythUser
{   
    /**
     * Returns Email
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return trim(trim($this->attributes['email']));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add the following method to myth-auth\src\Entities\User.php

```
public function getEmail()
    {
        return trim(trim($this->attributes['email']));
    }
```

then, anywhere in your app, you can call it with user()->getUsername()

You can do the same for username or any of the other user attributes.

Answer (score 0):

A!
Now that we have our new entity, we need to update our UserModel to return it instead of the default Myth:Auth version:

```php
class UserModel extends MythModel
{
    protected $returnType = 'App\Entities\User';
    ...
```